# blazor conditional binding ? can this be simplified?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, blazor

im building some blazor app and wanted to make wraper around select so it renders items from some casched dictionary values
so i have it like

```
@typeparam T
@inject DictService _dhttp;

@if (this.Label != null)
{
    <MudSelect T="T" @bind-Value="Value" For="@For" Label="@Label" @attributes=AllOtherAttributes>
        @if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null)
        {
          <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="null"> </MudSelectItem>
            @foreach (var item in _dict)
            {
               <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="item.Key">@item.Value</MudSelectItem>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            @foreach (var item in _dict)
            {
                <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="item.Key">@item.Value</MudSelectItem>
            }
        }
    </MudSelect>
}
else
{
    <MudSelect T="T" @bind-Value="Value" For="@For" @attributes=AllOtherAttributes>
        @if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null)
        {
          <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="null"> </MudSelectItem>
            @foreach (var item in _dict)
            {
               <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="item.Key">@item.Value</MudSelectItem>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            @foreach (var item in _dict)
            {
                <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="item.Key">@item.Value</MudSelectItem>
            }
        }
    </MudSelect>
}

@code{
 [Parameter]
    public string? Label {get;set;}
....
}
```

so can this be simplified ? best would be like

```
 <MudSelect T="T" @bind-Value="Value" For="@For" @if(Label != null){Label="@Label" }@attributes=AllOtherAttributes>
```

but this not correct for blazor ? (why?)

```
@if(this.Label != null)
{
    <MudSelect T="T" @bind-Value="Value" For="@For" Label="@Label" @attributes=AllOtherAttributes>
}
else
{
     <MudSelect T="T" @bind-Value="Value" For="@For" Label="@Label" @attributes=AllOtherAttributes>
}
        @if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null)
        {...
```

this is also not correct. why it does not allow this ?? requre all tags inside if to be closed. this is some limitation that i was not aware of....

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leverage off the `@attributes` parameter. But, if implemented correctly, you can pass `null` to the `Label` parameter, and the component should handle whether it should render or not.

If the component's implementation does not cater for `null`, and does something weird, you can add parameters dynamically using the `@attributes` parameter.

Example:

```
<MudSelect T="T" @bind-Value="Value" For="@For" @attributes="AllOtherAttributes">

@code {

protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
    AllOtherAttributes = new();

    if (AllOtherAttributes.ContainsKey("Label"))
    {
        if (Label == null)
        {
            AllOtherAttributes.Remove("Label"); //Remove Label
        }
        else
        {
            AllOtherAttributes["Label"] = Label; //Update Label
        }

    }
    else if (Label != null)
    {
        AllOtherAttributes.Add("Label", Label); //This adds dynamically and works for any Parameter
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is another improvement you can make:

```
<MudSelect T="T" @bind-Value="Value" For="@For" Label="@Label" @attributes=AllOtherAttributes>
    @if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="T" Value="default" />
    }
    @foreach (var item in _dict)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="T" Value="item.Key">@item.Value</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>
```

Simplified, and no need to change the Type for `T` to `int`. This will make this component work for any type.

Comment: thanks i thoutht about that but this throws Unhandled exception rendering component: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Label - MudSelect  have this explicitly typed so it needs to be same way

Comment: Obviously you will need to check if the dictionary already contains the label key. I will update my answer.

Comment: @d00lar, answer updated.

Comment: i need to change T to int because _dict is List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>

Comment: also <MudSelectItem T="T" Value="null"> </MudSelectItem> is not valit because canot converrt T to null

Comment: Then you need to include this type of information in your question. I answered based on what was provided. But, `T` should be of the same type though. Double check that you did not make a logical mistake.

Comment: use `default` instead of `null`

Comment: thanks alot this works fine with default. i changed this dict to be generic also :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is not correct because you are inside a blazor component and around a parameter. You could think of it as a function. You would not try to put some if statement inside the arguments of a function to specify if the argument is given or not. I don't think components in Blazor are any different for this aspect.

To avoid duplicated code, you can affect the values of your arguments, just like a function:

- put the content of the MudBlazor in a variable or a component.
- try to see if there is any value for Label that would give the same result than not providing the value at all.

Comment: put the content of the MudBlazor in a variable or a component. - can you show example?
second option is not possible - checked